# Switched to Intel Graphics, can't boot now (Failed to Start GPU off during boot)

Tags: boot, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime, gpu-driver

I just started using Ubuntu (also Linux), and I'm having so many problems. One of which is now, I can't boot to the OS because I switched to Intel graphics from Nvidia on the Nvidia X Server Settings app. When trying to boot, it bootloops. The screen keeps flashing.

It just hangs there. I can't even access to the command line to change it back to Nvidia.

My GPUs are Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia Geforce 710M.

What can I do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the nouveau drivers from grub. To do this when your computer is first booting up hold the shift key until you get into the grub menu.
When there press e and then go down to the line that starts with "linux" and go to the very end of that line (often times it's wordwrapped so adjust for that). At the very end attach
'nouveau.modeset=0' and press F10 to resume to boot.
This will only get you through this boot though and it's not a permanent fix. Once booted you can try undoing the change.